# How to get data from bloc stream from other page in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, stream-builder

I have a problem like this :
In Splash Page , i check in sharedpreference to get saved token when login successfully .If i have token , i request Api to get account information and move to next page like this:

```
 Future check() async {
    String _getToken = await splashBloc.getTokenFormSharedPref();
    if (_getToken=='0') {
      Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => LoginMain()));
    } else {
      splashBloc.getAccountInfo();
      Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomeScreenMain()));
    }
  }
```

and this is BLoC class:

```
class SplashBloc extends BlocBase{

  String _getToken = '';
  Future<String> getTokenFormSharedPref() async{
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    _getToken = (prefs.getString('token') ?? '0');
    return _getToken;
  }

  final accountInfoController = new StreamController<Account>();
  Sink<Account> get accountInfoSink => accountInfoController.sink;
  Stream<Account> get accountInfoStream => accountInfoController.stream;

  Future getAccountInfo() async{
    Account account = await NetworkService().getAccountInfo2(_getToken);
    accountInfoSink.add(account);
    print('from splash: '+account.fullName);
  }
  @override
  void dispose() {
    accountInfoController.close();
  }

}
```

When i check log , it totally request successfully and the problem is how can i acesss data in streambuilder in next page that is HomeScreenMain()?
Thanks for help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can declare a variable in HomeScreenMain() and send the data you received before to the class constructor like this:

```
HomeScreenMain() {
final data;
HomeScreenMain(this.data)

//....
}
```

and when you want to call this widget you can pass that data from block to this widget

Comment: i know your idea but this data call from api request and if we declare , it's definitely an instance of data , not that data.Btw , thanks

Comment: you are adding the data to your stream sink. so you can use the data that is coming to your bloc stream either by making it global or using a bloc provider. making global is easier so you just have to make an instance of your bloc at the end of bloc class like this: final bloc = SplashBloc();  then you can use your bloc and data anywhere.

Comment: oh yes , maybe that's the right way to use global variable. Thanks!

Comment: if u got ur answer and it worked accept the answer to close the question topic

Comment: This is right one , I choose to declare bloc class as global variable.
And in the class , i change the controller to BehaviorSubject.
Thanks you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You appear to use a very basic approach with BLoC. Not sure if my answer helps there.

But if you use the library flutter_bloc, then you can use on the next page
ˋfinal bloc = context.read;

This looks for a provider of this bloc type upstream in the Widget tree and assigns it to ˋbloc

Comment: i didn't use lib flutter_bloc . I create own bloc to use because i'm a new one to learn so i choose sink and stream to get deeper before use the library

Comment: I started last year at this point and would recommend using flutter_bloc right away, since it makes things much easier. Look at the examples at bloclibrary.dev, use dependency injection when initializing the bloc to make it better testable etc. Just my 2 Cents

Comment: thanks for sharing that to a newbie like me ! worth a try to library